# AzureAD B2C password reset url querystring ru and ctx

Tags: azure, password-recovery, azure-ad-b2c

When I use "Can't access your account?" link in sign in screen to reset my password, the URL contains "ru" in which it contains:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{your info}/reprocess?ctx=...
```

Does any one know how the ctx value is generated or how to get it?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CTX is used to store a information about the state of the app you were visiting before you got redirected. It is generated by the application that forwarded you to that page. You really cannot generate this information on your own, nor should you, unless you want to specifically store some state yourself.

Comment: I post a question here and that is why I try to generate CTX.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42213556/changing-azure-ad-b2c-sign-up-or-sign-in-policiess-forgot-password-link

But I agree with what you said which make sense.